# How run a specific GraphQLTestCase test in graphene-django?

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

import json

from graphene_django.utils.testing import GraphQLTestCase

from swapi.schema import schema

class FirstTestCase(GraphQLTestCase):
fixtures = ['app/fixtures/unittest.json']
GRAPHQL_SCHEMA = schema

```
def test_people_query(self):
    response = self.query(
        '''
            query{
              allPlanets {
                edges{
                  node{
                    id
                    name
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        ''',
    )
    
    self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)

    content = json.loads(response.content)
    self.assertEqual(len(content['data']['allPlanets']['edges']), 61)

def test_two(self):
    # Some test logic
    pass
```

I have the above code, I only need to run the test_two. I already know this command python manage.py test runs all tests. Please help thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can run an individual test method using syntax like:

```
python manage.py test my_app.tests.FirstTestCase.test_two
```

(Where `my_app.tests` is the Python dotted path to your file containing `FirstTestCase`.) More info in the [Django documentation for Running tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests).